# WiFi adapter working on pc but not on RPi Zero W

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w

I'm trying to make a sort of "hack" box to do pen-testing with and I am using the RPi Zero W. I have a Panda PAUO5 USB wifi adapter that I have tested working with Kali Linux on my laptop. It works fabulously on my laptop, but only sort of works on the RPi. It can connect and to networks and it will even go into monitor mode just fine but once there it won't pick up any APs in airodump-ng when I target my home wifi. Like I said, I tested it with my laptop running the same Distro on the same release but it just doesn't work on the RPi.

I know that this is more a question for the Linux stack exchange but thought I would ask here because it works just fine when not on the RPi